# Don't understand this SyntaxError about the metaclass

Tags: python, python-2.7, ethereum

Codes below are atomic.py from the pyrlp package, which is a library of pyethereum.

```
import abc


class Atomic(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    """ABC for objects that can be RLP encoded as is."""
    pass


Atomic.register(bytes)
Atomic.register(bytearray)
```

And here is the error information from the console:

```
from rlp.atomic import Atomic
  File "/Users/jerryin/Desktop/pyeth/pyrlp/rlp/atomic.py", line 4
    class Atomic(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've not modified the project since it was imported. Could anyone please tell me what's wrong with this?

Plus, the interpreter I used for this project is Python 2.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 2 does not support the `metaclass` keyword argument to classes, and [pyrlp dropped support for Python 2 in April 2018](https://github.com/ethereum/pyrlp/commit/a2fb60d21bd59309fa484e07db3399ab4dac00b7).

Use Python 3 instead.

Comment: The question has been asked in terms of 'python 2.7' environment.
There are valid reasons some times why that version is in use on the project.

In particular, if someone tries to follow some manual that has not been updated since library moved on by removing support of 2.x version of python. It might be valuable to share how to install 'pyrlp' of older version with python 2.x version.

Answer (score 3):

`pip install protobuf==3.17.3` should normally fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Python 2 "syntax" for metaclasses is a magic class attribute:

```
class Atomic(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
```

The abc package also has a regular class using ABCMeta, which allows using inheritance instead:

```
class Atomic(abc.ABC):
    pass
```

Note that unless you want to patch the library, you should use Python 3 instead. The library is not made for Python 2.